# What is this V-shaped strut on the landing gear for?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

On [this video](https://youtu.be/mqPMANOEG7Y?t=3m26s) from Captain Joe, you can see that the landing gear of the airplane has got some sort of v-shaped strut connecting the two moving parts.
[image: v-shaped strut]

I think that I saw the same thing on some vespas with a suspension in the front wheel.

What are they for ?

Comment: Good question, and on-scope for this site. However, you might have better luck at [Aviation.SE], since that's full of people who know airplanes.

Comment: Indeed, but I saw the same thing on [motorbikes](https://www.morebikes.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/05-Vespa-GTS-125150.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the mechanism that allows the piston to move so absorbing the landing forces, while making sure that there is no rotation of the wheel assembly which would create a huge amount of side loading and possibly cause the landing gear to fail.

I have had the opportunity to visit Airbus and stand next to some of the units used to test these... serious engineering, but then 230 tonnes does take some controlling...

Comment: +1, To my naive eye it seems that a spline-shaft coupling would serve the same purpose.  Why was a spline not used for this?  Perhaps manufacturing tolerances are difficult to achieve because of the complex geometry of a spline?   Are there any planes that do use spline shaft couplings for landing gear?  Seems like the gear in the pictures would be heavier.

Comment: That piston - well the one I looked at for real - not just a photo, was 30cm diameter approx - given the loading and the high pressures the hydraulics run at 200bar then trying to seal a splined shaft and socket would be a challenge.

Comment: it also provides a support for a constant length path down to the wheels for the hydraulic and electrical lines (there is another lighter strut doing the same in front)

Answer (score 1):

I have a small plane and also  fly with other small single engine prop airplanes, Such as Cessna, Cherokee, Moony and the like.

They do have a similar structure providing alignment and resisting shimmying of the wheel when the plane hits a bump on the tarmac.

This is likely the same structure except possibly doing some more sophisticated things in addition to that.